# Ruta GET agregar producto

Tags: javascript-objeto

Me pide crear una variable ("**producto**") que tenga propiedades con valor "`null`".
Luego se debe crear una ruta que use el método `get` y que apunte a "**/producto/agregar**".
Esta deberá devolver la variable producto que cree.
Pero al hacerlo me devuelve "La ruta debe devolver la variable producto".
este es mi código:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

  let producto ={
    tipoProducto : "null",
    precio : "null",
    cantidad : "null"} ;

app.get("/producto/agregar", (req, res) => {
  
    res.send(producto);
});
```